# WebMethod called using jQuery returning server error when fetching large amounts of data. Is there a limitation on the data size?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asmx, pagemethods

I am using jQuery to call WebMethods (page methods) on a ASPX page.  When I return up to 200 items, it works fine.  But if I attempt to pull more than that it returns a server error.  I am not sure how to see the exact error message.

If I pull the data on load and insert it to a javascript variable, it works fine, but not via the Ajax post.

I copied the text from 300 records to a text file and it is showing as 136KB.  Am I running into a Ajax data size limitation?  Wouldn't that just give me a browser error?

Is there any way to get the contents of the error message from the server?

UPDATE: For anyone wondering, you can change the max json response length up to 4MB in the web.config.

Comment: If you run the site in Firefox with FireBug and enable the net panel, you can see the actual response (in html of course) and get the actual error message from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely need either **Firebug**, **Fiddler**, or an equivalent tool for web development in general but especially for ajax interactions. The reason you're not seeing a 'browser error' is because it's an async request.

You can monitor *all* requests (including async ones) using these tools so you can see exactly what the client sent, what the server replied with, and what the error is.

HTH